# Taking forever to save to database, vb.net datagrid bound controls

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need help, here is what I have.. I have several custom forms I'm developing using data grids with vb.net.  I have a dataset that has basically two tables. when I click save calls the code

```
 Me.ANALYSISBindingSource.EndEdit()
 Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TreatPointDataSet)
```

but it takes forever to save almost a minute...
i'm not sure why it would take this long. funny thing is when I create another dataset of the same tables and drag the grid over it takes 2 seconds to save. wondering why it would be so much different

Comment: Maybe the bad performing dataset has many relations or many tables changed?

Comment: I guess the problem is most likely in your database design and not in your .net code ... so you should post something about that ((clustered) indexes, relations, constraints, triggers) ...

Comment: actually I found out that I have a datagrid, text boxes and drop downs bound controls... but as soon as I put a date field drop down it slows the save into the database so bad.. why is that?